# ListView not saving changes after updating its screen

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

every time i update my screen (change rotation or leave the screen and then go back to it) it doesn't save the updated list and i go back to the default list. thank you in advance <3
MovieActivity:

```
public class MovieActivity : Activity, ListView.IOnItemClickListener, Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener, ListView.IOnItemLongClickListener
{
   public static List<Movie> movieList { get; set; }
    MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
    ListView lv;
    Button btnAdd;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.movie_page);
        // Create your application here
        btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
       Bitmap vannila_sky_pic = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Application.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Vanilla_Sky);
        Bitmap jimmyneutron_pic = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Application.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Jimmy_Neutron_Boy_Genius_film);
        Movie m1 = new Movie(90, "Vanilla Sky", "James", vannila_sky_pic);
        Movie m2 = new Movie(124, "jimmy neutron", "arthur", jimmyneutron_pic);
     movieList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Movie>();
        movieList.Add(m1);
        movieList.Add(m2);
        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, movieList);
        lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lv);
        lv.Adapter = movieAdapter;
        lv.OnItemClickListener = this;
        lv.OnItemLongClickListener = this;
        btnAdd.SetOnClickListener(this);
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        if (movieAdapter != null)
        {
            movieAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(EditMovieActivity));
        Movie temp = MovieActivity.movieList[position];
        intent.PutExtra("pos", position);
        StartActivity(intent);
        
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if(v == btnAdd)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(EditMovieActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
            
        }
    }

    public bool OnItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        MovieActivity.movieList.RemoveAt(position);
        movieAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
}
```

EditMovieActivity:` public class EditMovieActivity : Activity, Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener
{
Button btnSave, btnAddPic;

```
    EditText etTitle, etDirector, etAvg, etLength;

    Bitmap bitmap;
    int pos = -1;
    ImageView iv;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.edit_movie);
        iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivMovie);
        btnSave = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSave);
        btnAddPic = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAddPic);
        etTitle = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etTitle);
        etDirector = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etDirector);
        etAvg = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etAvg);
        etLength = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etLength);
        pos = Intent.GetIntExtra("pos", -1);//-1 is default
        btnAddPic.SetOnClickListener(this);
        btnSave.SetOnClickListener(this);
        if (pos != -1)// update 
        {
            Movie temp = MovieActivity.movieList[pos];
            Toast.MakeText(this, "position is  " + pos, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            etTitle.Text = temp.getTitle();
            etDirector.Text = temp.getDirector();
            etAvg.Text = "" + temp.getAvg();
            etLength.Text = "" + temp.getLength();
            bitmap = temp.getBitmap();
            iv.SetImageBitmap(temp.getBitmap());
        }
        else // new movie
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "lets add new item ", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == btnAddPic)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        else
            if (v == btnSave)
        {
            int length = int.Parse(etLength.Text);
            int avg = int.Parse(etAvg.Text);
            string title = etTitle.Text;
            string director = etDirector.Text;
            Movie m = null;
            if (pos != -1)//updates
            {
                m = new Movie(length, title, director, bitmap);
                MovieActivity.movieList[pos] = m;
                Finish();
            }
            else// adds new movie
            {
                m = new Movie(length, title, director, bitmap);
                MovieActivity.movieList.Add(m);
                Finish();
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0)//coming from camera
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                bitmap = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
                iv.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

Movie:

```
 public class Movie
{
    private int length;
    private string title;
    private string director;
    private int avg;
    private Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap;
    public Movie(int length, string title, string director,Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap )
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.title = title;
        this.director = director;
        this.avg = 0;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;

    }
    public void setBitmap(Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
    public Android.Graphics.Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        return bitmap;
    }
    public void setAvg(int avg)
    {
        this.avg = avg;
    }
    public int getAvg()
    {
        return avg;
    }
    public void setDirector(string director)
    {
        this.director = director;
    }
    public string getDirector()
    {
        return director;
    }
    public void setTitle(string title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public string getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    public void setLength(int length)
    {
        this.length = length;
    }
    public int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }

}
```

MovieAdapter:

```
class MovieAdapter:BaseAdapter<Movie>
{
    Android.Content.Context context;
    List<Movie> objects;
    
    public MovieAdapter(Android.Content.Context context, System.Collections.Generic.List<Movie> objects)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public List<Movie> GetList()
    {
        return this.objects;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return this.objects.Count; }
    }

    public override Movie this[int position]
    {
        get { return this.objects[position]; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Android.Views.LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((MovieActivity)context).LayoutInflater;
        Android.Views.View view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.movie_layoutxml, parent, false);
        TextView tvTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvTitle);
        TextView tvDirector = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvDirector);
        TextView tvLength = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvlength);
        TextView tvAvg = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvAvg);
        ImageView ivCover = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivCover);
        Movie temp = objects[position];
        if(temp != null)
        {
            ivCover.SetImageBitmap(temp.getBitmap());
            tvAvg.Text = "" + temp.getAvg();
            tvTitle.Text = temp.getTitle();
            tvLength.Text ="" + temp.getLength();
            tvDirector.Text = temp.getDirector();
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, listview don't update when you change some listview item.

I do one sample that you can take a look, create  public static List and ListAdapter.

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
   public static List<Earthquake> earthquakes;
    ListView lvw;
   public static EarthquakeListAdapter listadapter;
    Button btnadd;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

         earthquakes = new List<Earthquake>
        {
            new Earthquake{Place="Nepal", DateOccured="May 12, 2015" },
            new Earthquake{Place="Solomon Sea", DateOccured="May 7, 2015" },
            new Earthquake{Place="Papua New Guinea", DateOccured="May 5, 2015" },
            new Earthquake{Place="Nepal", DateOccured="April 25, 2015" },
            new Earthquake{Place="Taiwan", DateOccured="April 20, 2015" },
            new Earthquake{Place="Papua New Guinea", DateOccured="March 29, 2015" },
            new Earthquake{Place="Flores Sea", DateOccured="Febdruary 27, 2015" },
            new Earthquake{Place="Mid-Atlantic range", DateOccured="Febdruary 13, 2015" }
        };
        lvw = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvwEarthquakes);
        btnadd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        btnadd.Click += Btnadd_Click;
        listadapter= new EarthquakeListAdapter(this, earthquakes);
        lvw.Adapter = listadapter;
        lvw.ItemLongClick += Lvw_ItemLongClick; ;
        lvw.ItemClick += Lvw_ItemClick;
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        Log.Debug("OnResume", "OnResume called, app is ready to interact with the user");
        base.OnResume();
        listadapter = new EarthquakeListAdapter(this, earthquakes);
        lvw.Adapter = listadapter;
    }

    private void Lvw_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = earthquakes[e.Position];
        MainActivity.earthquakes.Remove(item);
        List<Earthquake> items = MainActivity.earthquakes;
        listadapter = new EarthquakeListAdapter(this, earthquakes);
        lvw.Adapter = listadapter;

    }

    private void Lvw_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(editActivity));
        //Earthquake temp = MainActivity.earthquakes[e.Position];
        string position = e.Position.ToString();
        intent.PutExtra("p", position);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

  

 

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

public class Earthquake
{
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string DateOccured { get; set; }
}

 public class EarthquakeListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Earthquake>
{

    List<Earthquake> earthquakes;
    Activity context;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="earthquakeList"></param>
    public EarthquakeListAdapter(Activity currentContext, List<Earthquake> earthquakeList) : base()
    {
        this.earthquakes = earthquakeList;
        this.context = currentContext;
    }

    public override Earthquake this[int position]
    {
        get { return earthquakes.ToArray()[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return earthquakes.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = earthquakes.ToArray()[position].Place;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text2).Text = earthquakes.ToArray()[position].DateOccured;
        }
        return view;
    }

   
}

 public class editActivity : Activity
{
    EditText edittext1;
    EditText edittext2;
    int position;
    Button button;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.editlayout1);
        // Create your application here
        edittext1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        edittext2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
        button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += Butto1_Click;

        string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("p");
       position = Convert.ToInt32(text);
        edittext1.Text = MainActivity.earthquakes[position].Place;
        edittext2.Text = MainActivity.earthquakes[position].DateOccured;
    }

    private void Butto1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainActivity.earthquakes[position] = new Earthquake() { Place = edittext1.Text, DateOccured = edittext2.Text };

        OnBackPressed();
       
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanted it to like save the list view even if i totally close the app.

Comment: @Jonathan Not sure what you mean, what is **save the list view even if i totally close the app**,you want to display the updated listview when app open again?

Comment: yep, but i managed to fix it i just added a database that the list gets saved to

Comment: @Jonathan yes, it is better to use database when update data, then load data from database to display in ListView.